# XSLT - add attribute to node dynamically

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have xml like follows,

```
<doc>
<p type="Foot">
    <link ref="http://www.facebook.com">
        <c type="Hyperlink">www.facebook.com</c>
    </link>
</p>
 <p type="End">
    <link ref="http://www.google.com">
        <c type="Hyperlink">www.google.com.com</c>
    </link>
</p>
</doc>
```

what I need to do is add dynamic id attributes to `<p>` node which has attribute `"Foot"` and `"End"`. SO I have written following xsl,

```
<xsl:template match="p[@type='Foot' or @type='End']" priority="1">
     <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:value-of select="'foot-'"/> 
            <xsl:number count="p[@type='Foot' or @type='End']" level="any"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:next-match/>
    </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

it gives me following result

```
<doc>
<p id="foot-1"><p type="Foot">
    <link ref="http://www.facebook.com">
        <c type="Hyperlink">www.facebook.com</c>
    </link>
</p></p>
 <p id="foot-2"><p type="End">
    <link ref="http://www.google.com">
        <c type="Hyperlink">www.google.com.com</c>
    </link>
</p></p>
</doc>
```

as above result xml, it add duplicate

node and add new attribute. but what I need is this,

```
<doc>
<p id="foot-1 type="Foot">
    <link ref="http://www.facebook.com">
        <c type="Hyperlink">www.facebook.com</c>
    </link>
</p></p>
 <p id="foot-2 type="End">
    <link ref="http://www.google.com">
        <c type="Hyperlink">www.google.com.com</c>
    </link>
</p></p>
</doc>
```

How can I get this output from changing mu xsl?

Comment: I've not tried it, but I think you need copy-of to copy your attributes and then apply-templates rather than next-match to avoid reprocessing the same node.

Comment: @Giles,thing is I have written more transformation for <xsl:template match="p[@type='Foot') andr <xsl:template match="p[@type='End']. if I uses xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/> those transformation is not working. those are working only when I use <xsl:next-match>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is likely to be something we can't see from your question- you're calling `xsl:next-match`, in a template that's already outputting a `p` tag from the `xsl:copy` instruction. If the next match, whatever that happens to be also does `xsl:copy`, you're going to get a second `p` tag inside the first, like you're seeing.

It sounds like what you need to do is have another template with higher priority that matches only `p`, have this do the `<xsl:copy>`, call `<xsl:next-match>` inside that then process subnodes, and remove the `<xsl:copy>` from the lower-priority templates that match specific cases.

```
<xsl:template match="p" priority="2">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:next-match/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p[@type='Foot']" priority="1">
  <xsl:attribute name="id">
    <xsl:value-of select="'foot-'"/> 
    <xsl:number count="p[@type='Foot' or @type='End']" level="any"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:next-match/>
</xsl:template>

etc..
```

Incidentally, you don't need `<xsl:value-of select="'foot-'"/>`- if it's just a constant, then `<xsl:text>foot-</xsl:text>` will do.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. :) thing is I have written more transformation for <xsl:template match="p[@type='Foot') andr <xsl:template match="p[@type='End']. if I uses xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/> those transformation is not working. those are working only when I use <xsl:next-match>.

Comment: Added in a possible solution with this additional info.